# Crop Thumbnail Featured Image

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

For some reason when I crop my thumbnails using the WordPress 3.6.1 media library GUI functionality it doesn't seem to effect the Thumbnails shown on my portfolio page? Even though the thumbnail appears as cropped in the backend it still appears incorrectly on the portfolio page?

Below is an excerpt of code from the portfolio page. As you can see it uses the Medium size thumbnail.

```
<article class="post">
          <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) : // Check if thumbnail exists ?>    
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark">
        <figure>
        <?php the_post_thumbnail('medium'); // Declare pixel size you need inside the array ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    </figure>
    <!-- /post thumbnail -->
    <div class="cover">
        <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
        <time pubdate="<?php the_date(); ?>"><?php the_date('Y-m-d', '<h2>', '</h2>'); ?></time>
    </div>
          </a> 
        </article>
```

In functions.php I have the following:

```
// Add Thumbnail Theme Support
add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');
add_image_size('large', 700, '', true); // Large Thumbnail
add_image_size('medium', 250, '', true); // Medium Thumbnail
add_image_size('small', 120, '', true); // Small Thumbnail
add_image_size('custom-size', 700, 200, true); // Custom Thumbnail
```

Any reason Why I cannot crop a portrait image I have uploaded to the Media library to landscape format via the WordPress GUI?

Answer (score 0):

> Any reason Why I cannot crop a potrait image I have uploaded to the
>   Media library to landscape format?

Because you have no height specified, the images are getting cropped to 700px width (for large images) but the height can remain as high as possible (proportional)

Let's say you have an image 700px*1500px and you want to convert it to a langscape image then you'll need the following size:

```
add_image_size('large', 700, '200', true);
```

Change the `200` to your liking. Read more: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size

Comment: Sorry I don't think I have been clear enough in my question. I am talking about editing the image in the wordpress GUI not via the functions.asp file...

Comment: If it's shown correctly on the backend it's probably just your browser cache displaying the previous image version.